# How to use Integer input key for KeyValueTextInputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to read a file which has lines in the following format.

100,1:2:3
200,10:20:30

Assuming that the inputs will always be numbers, I am trying to read the file by setting the input key and value as `IntWritable` and `Text` respectively. But when I run it, I get the following error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable`

Now, though I understand what it means, I am unable to figure out how to read the key as an integer. The code runs fine if I read the key as a `Text` as well. I have checked everywhere in the code if I have missed the configuration, but it seems fine to me.

```
conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", "|");

conf.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
conf.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

conf.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

I have also checked the mapper class and methods (There is no reducer). Is it that the `KeyValueTextInputFormat` can read the key as only Text? I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
EG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.java?view=markup) of `KeyValueTextInputFormat`, it extends from `FileInputFormat<Text, Text>`. What that means is that both key and value for your input are expected to be `Text`.

You could fix that implementing your own `RecordReader` which you could model after the `KeyValueLineRecordReder` described [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/KeyValueLineRecordReader.java?view=markup), but extend from `RecordReader<IntWritable, Text>` instead and modify the code accordingly.

When you have your `RecordReader`, you can create your own `InputFormat` and use your new `RecordReader` and then in your main code you just need to set your new `InputFormat` like this:

```
conf.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueMyInputFormat.class);
```

Another approach I would recommend if you're really worried about performance is that you could use `SequenceFileInputFormat`. This involves storing your input as SequenceFiles, which means it will be in binary format directly. This avoids the overhead of parsing every line as you need to do in your case. You can use this format like this:

```
conf.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
```

Comment: I would try the `SequenceFileInputFormat` and get back to you. Thanks!